# React / Javascript If statement inside map

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make a table which will have different coloured rows depending on an attribute which is derived from a map function:

```
       var tableData = this.state.data.map(attribute =>

            {if(attribute.duplicate.toString()== "true")
                return <tr className="table-success">;
            else
                return <tr className="table-warning">;
            }
                <td> {count++} </td>
                ...
                <td> {attribute.duplicate.toString()} </td>
            </tr>
       );
```

Now `var tableData` gets passed through to the actual table:

```
<div>
        <div>
            <table className="table">
                <tr className="thead-inverse">
                    <th> # </th>
                    ...
                    <th> duplicate </th>
                </tr>
                    {tableData}
            </table>

        </div>
    </div>
```

But I get the following error:

```
[INFO] Module build failed: SyntaxError: C:/Users/.../all.js: Unterminated JSX contents (78:14)
[INFO] 
[INFO]   76 | 
[INFO]   77 |             </div>
[INFO] > 78 |         </div>
[INFO]      |               ^
```

Any ideas what the problem is, or another way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: You can't leave the element open like that, JSX needs elements with closed tags.

Comment: @MinusFour but everything is being closed, are you refering to the <tr> tag?

Comment: the return in the if statement exits the map call.  The code you wrote just doesn't make much sense.  If you re-create this on codesandbox.io then it will be easy for us to help.

Comment: @gabrriel_bu exactly, you are leaving the tr tag open

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just move the conditional logic inside the `className` or assign it to a variable and then use it inside the `tr`.

```
   var tableData = this.state.data.map(attribute => 
       <tr className={attribute.duplicate.toString() == "true" ? "table-success" : "table-warning"}>
            <td> {count++} </td>
            ...
            <td> {attribute.duplicate.toString()} </td>
        </tr>
   );
```

Comment: You should also take a look at [If-Else in JSX[(https://react-cn.github.io/react/tips/if-else-in-JSX.html). It will explain why you cannot use if else inside JSX. The short is: if-else statements don't work inside JSX. This is because JSX is just syntactic sugar for function calls and object construction.